# converting numpy of string to numpy characters python

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I am reading data from a URL and trying to convert it to digits for further analysis on jupyter. It is a gene sequence where each gene would code for 4 binary digits. A --> 0001, C --> 0010, G --> 0100 and T --> 1000. For example, I want to go from CGGT to 0010010001001000. So far, I've been able to remove the empty space and convert it to a string. However I am unable to go from string to char and char to digits. I am using numpy arrays and have made these attempts but to no avail.

```
charGenes = [var for var in genes if var]
```

and

```
charGenes = np.char.array(genes)
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

url = "https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/molecular- biology/splice-junction-gene-sequences/splice.data"
file = pd.read_csv(url, delimiter=',', header=None,dtype='str')

X = file[2]
y = file[0]

myGenes = np.array(X)
stringGenes = myGenes.astype(str)

spaceGenes = stringGenes.reshape( stringGenes.size, 1)

genes = np.char.strip(spaceGenes)
genes
```

This is the output:

```
array([['CCAGCTGCATCACAGGAGGCCAGCGAGCAGGTCTGTTCCAAGGGCCTTCGAGCCAGTCTG'],
   ['AGACCCGCCGGGAGGCGGAGGACCTGCAGGGTGAGCCCCACCGCCCCTCCGTGCCCCCGC'],
   ['GAGGTGAAGGACGTCCTTCCCCAGGAGCCGGTGAGAAGCGCAGTCGGGGGCACGGGGATG'],
   ...,
   ['TCTCGGGGGCGGCCGGCGCGGCGGGGAGCGGTCCCCGGCCGCGGCCCCGACGTGTGTGTC'],
   ['ATTCTACTTAGTAAACATAATTTCTTGTGCTAGATAACCAAATTAAGAAAACCAAAACAA'],
   ['AGGCTGCCTATCAGAAGGTGGTGGCTGGTGTGGCTGCTGCTCTGGCTCACAAGTACCATT']],
  dtype='<U79')
```

Any help of pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a method using a lookup table:

```
>>> alphabet = np.array(list('ACGT'))
>>> alphabet
array(['A', 'C', 'G', 'T'], dtype='<U1')
```

To use a lookup table we need to reinterpret the letters as indices, this is done via view casting:

```
>>> alph_as_num = alphabet.view(np.int32)
>>> alph_as_num
array([65, 67, 71, 84], dtype=int32)
```

We can now build the lookup table it needs `85` slots of which we will actually only be using 4, namely `65`, `67`, `71` and `84`. As for the output format we are free to choose what best meets our requirements:

Example one - output as bytestring:

```
>>> lookup_1 = np.zeros((alph_as_num.max()+1), dtype='S4')
>>> lookup_1[alph_as_num] = [b'0001000'[i:i+4] for i in range(4)]
```

Example two - output as `uint8`:

```
>>> lookup_2 = np.zeros((alph_as_num.max()+1), dtype=np.uint8)
>>> lookup_2[alph_as_num] = 1 << np.arange(4)
```

Example three - output as four `uint8` per letter:

```
>>> lookup_3 = np.zeros((alph_as_num.max()+1, 4), dtype=np.uint8)
>>> lookup_3[alph_as_num[::-1]] = np.identity(4)
```

Now let's apply this to a `100` letter sequence:

```
>>> seq
array(['CATTTCTCCACCATTTTGGTTTTTCATTGATCCGTTAGGTGGAGCCGGACTATGTCTACCGAAAGATGCACCTGCGCCGGGTCTGGTCTATCTCTTAATG'],
      dtype='<U100')
```

The translation is compact and fast since it relies only on

- **numpy's builtin advanced indexing** which gives us very fast lookup (much faster than Python dictionaries for example)
- **view casting** which is essentially free since all it does is reinterpret the data buffer (no copying or transformation whatsoever)

Example one - bytestrings:

```
>>> lookup_1[seq.view(np.int32)]
array([b'0010', b'0001', b'1000', b'1000', b'1000', b'0010', b'1000',
       b'0010', b'0010', b'0001', b'0010', b'0010', b'0001', b'1000',
       b'1000', b'1000', b'1000', b'0100', b'0100', b'1000', b'1000',
       b'1000', b'1000', b'1000', b'0010', b'0001', b'1000', b'1000',
       b'0100', b'0001', b'1000', b'0010', b'0010', b'0100', b'1000',
       b'1000', b'0001', b'0100', b'0100', b'1000', b'0100', b'0100',
       b'0001', b'0100', b'0010', b'0010', b'0100', b'0100', b'0001',
       b'0010', b'1000', b'0001', b'1000', b'0100', b'1000', b'0010',
       b'1000', b'0001', b'0010', b'0010', b'0100', b'0001', b'0001',
       b'0001', b'0100', b'0001', b'1000', b'0100', b'0010', b'0001',
       b'0010', b'0010', b'1000', b'0100', b'0010', b'0100', b'0010',
       b'0010', b'0100', b'0100', b'0100', b'1000', b'0010', b'1000',
       b'0100', b'0100', b'1000', b'0010', b'1000', b'0001', b'1000',
       b'0010', b'1000', b'0010', b'1000', b'1000', b'0001', b'0001',
       b'1000', b'0100'], dtype='|S4')
```

As a matter of preference these can also be view cast into one long sequence:

```
>>> lookup_1[seq.view(np.int32)].view('S400')
array([b'0010000110001000100000101000001000100001001000100001100010001000100001000100100010001000100010000010000110001000010000011000001000100100100010000001010001001000010001000001010000100010010001000001001010000001100001001000001010000001001000100100000100010001010000011000010000100001001000101000010000100100001000100100010001001000001010000100010010000010100000011000001010000010100010000001000110000100'],
      dtype='|S400')
```

Example two - `uint8`:

```
>>> lookup_2[seq.view(np.int32)]
array([2, 1, 8, 8, 8, 2, 8, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8,
       8, 8, 2, 1, 8, 8, 4, 1, 8, 2, 2, 4, 8, 8, 1, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 1, 4,
       2, 2, 4, 4, 1, 2, 8, 1, 8, 4, 8, 2, 8, 1, 2, 2, 4, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1,
       8, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 8, 4, 2, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 8, 2, 8, 4, 4, 8, 2,
       8, 1, 8, 2, 8, 2, 8, 8, 1, 1, 8, 4], dtype=uint8)
```

Example 3 - four `uint8` per letter; but let's use a different `seq` with multiple rows:

```
>>> seq
array([['CCCT'],
       ['GCGA']], dtype='<U4')
>>> lookup_3[seq.view(np.int32)].reshape(len(seq), -1)
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Comment: Simple and effective solution, however, any simpler way to have the result as int or bytes compared to the previous method. Although more concise, i need the end array to be in the mentioned format to continue my analysis on the data

Comment: @ankit the beauty of the lookup table is that you can put what you like in it. What exactly are your requirements? You want numbers `1,2,4,8` of type `np.uint8`?

Comment: I will split them into training and test data, and apply classification methods to them such as k nearest neighbors and neural networks. These classification methods usually require int's or bytes. So yes, uint8 is preferred

Comment: @ankit ok, updated. Let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: it works to some extent. I get my values except it pads each row with the value 49. Maybe because my array is 2 dimensional?
Example:

    array([[  2,   2,   1,   4,   2,   8,   4,   2,   1,   8,   2,   1,   2,
          1,   4,   4,   1,   4,   4,   2,   2,   1,   4,   2,   4,   1,
          4,   2,   1,   4,   4,   8,   2,   8,   4,   8,   8,   2,   2,
          1,   1,   4,   4,   4,   2,   2,   8,   8,   2,   4,   1,   4,
          2,   2,   1,   4,   8,   2,   8,   4,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,
         49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,  49,
         49],

Comment: @ankit Yes, and because the data do not fill the rows: You can see that the `dtype` is `<U79`, i.e. 79 unicode characters per row. But if you  count the letters they are only 60. The rest is zero padded and `49` happens to be the (essentially random) lookup value of zero; indeed, there are 19 49's and 60 proper values. But provided each row has the same number 60 of valid letters this is easy to fix: just cut the result at column 60: `result = result[:, :60]`.

Comment: ya I did that, was just wondering why. Will mark this as correct answer, thanks for your help

Comment: You seem to have a nice grasp on this, if I was to instead replace my gene values with the original coding (A --> 0001, C --> 0010, G --> 0100 and T --> 1000) and have it saved as individual integers, what would you suggest. For example, ACGT and TGCA would be stored as array[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]].

Comment: @ankit added it as a third example.

Comment: You should use `np.zero` instead of `np.empty` to easily detect any unexpected characters.

Comment: @Daniel good idea. I'd change it but - and this is actually true: my page layout is so screwed up that I can't reach the edit button anymore (Firefox...). But you feel free to edit if you like. I'd actually be grateful. - Nevermind, seems like adding this comment changed the state somehow. So I've done it myself.

Comment: @Paul Panzer what if I have numpy array of an audio file and I want to create words form it?  Any helps please

Answer (score 3):

Numpy has a `char.replace` method (see [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.core.defchararray.replace.html#numpy.core.defchararray.replace)). All you need to do is this:

```
genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'A', '1')
genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'C', '2')
genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'G', '4')
genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'T', '8')
```

To convert this to an `int` array,

```
genes = genes.astype(int)
```

you can then use [bitwise operations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) on the arrays.

---

As pointed out in the comments, the resulting sequence is limited in length. A way to solve this:

```
genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'A', '1')
genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'C', '2')
genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'G', '4')
genes = np.char.replace(genes, 'T', '8')

>>> genes
array([['12481248'],
       ['12481248']], dtype='|S8')
```

Insert a comma between the numbers

```
genes = np.char.join(',', genes)

>>> genes
array([['1,2,4,8,1,2,4,8'],
       ['1,2,4,8,1,2,4,8']], dtype='|S15')
```

Split based on the comma and convert back to a purely `np.char.array`

```
genes = np.char.array(np.char.split(genes, ','))

>>> genes
chararray([[['1', '2', '4', '8', '1', '2', '4', '8']],

           [['1', '2', '4', '8', '1', '2', '4', '8']]], dtype='|S1')
```

Convert to an `int` array:

```
genes = np.array(genes, dtype=int)

>>> genes
array([[[1, 2, 4, 8, 1, 2, 4, 8]],

       [[1, 2, 4, 8, 1, 2, 4, 8]]])
```

Remove the intermediate dimension of size `1`:

```
genes = genes.reshape(list(genes.shape[:-2]) + [genes.shape[-1]])

>>> genes
array([[1, 2, 4, 8, 1, 2, 4, 8],
       [1, 2, 4, 8, 1, 2, 4, 8]])
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure OP wants to convert a string to a byte array.

Comment: The answer does help, as int can work for my analysis. However byte is indeed preferred. Also, astype has a length limit and since my gene is pretty long, any way to overcome that issue?

Comment: @ankit Python doesn't display bytes as `1` and `0`, so you can replace `ACGT` with `1248` instead - you can then use [bitwise operations](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) on the NumPy arrays directly. Hopefully that also solves your length problem.

Comment: @droooze even by replacing with 1248 (single digit) per gene, my sequence still exceeds the allowed length. My sequence is 60 genes where as the limit is 32 I believe

Comment: @droooze I have never used numpy before, how would I proceed to split and do all the steps with 1280 gene sequences of 60 genes each. In the code above, they are currently in the genes array, with one sequence per row.

Comment: @ankit I've updated the answer, hopefully it works better now.